# NHibernate: How to return scalar value using CreateSQLQuery with native SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I'm trying to get a scalar value using a native SQL query and my statement looks like

```
var deptName =session.CreateSQLQuery(@"Select d.deptName from employee e,dept d Where e.deptId=d.deptID and e.EmpID=?")
                    .AddScalar("deptName", NHibernateUtil.String)
                    .SetCacheable(true)
                    .SetCacheMode(CacheMode.Normal)
                    .SetParameter(0, "12345").List();
```

And the corresponding SQL from SQL Server Profiler is correct and it is returning the desired value

```
exec sp_executesql N'select d.deptName from employee e, dept d
                            where e.empId=@p0 
                            and e.deptId=d.deptId',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'12345'
```

But the `typeof` `deptName` is `System.Collections.IList {System.Collections.Generic.List<object>}` and also when I try to access the `deptName` with `deptName[0].ToString()` it is returning `System.Object[]` instead of the actual value.

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell it you only want scalar:

```
var deptName = session.CreateSQLQuery("...").UniqueResult<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is all correct, but at the end while returning the value, you are converting the scalar output to list. Observe the `.List()` at the end of your code. That is the problem.

Though your SQL query selects only one column from one row, NHibernate have no way to learn that *that* is the case. You can instruct NHibernate to convert the output to scalar value by replacing `.List()` call with `.UniqueResult<string>()` call.

The `.UniqueResult<string>()` call is again two fold. The [`UniqueResult`](http://mausch.github.io/nhibernate-3.2.0GA/html/33e94a2d-13c5-0643-bebb-a5a6ac9eb1fc.htm) will not return scalar, it may return single row (entity instance) based on generic parameter passed to it. If no matching row found, it will return `null`. If multiple rows found, it will throw `NonUniqueResultException` as seen in the source code [here](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Impl/AbstractQueryImpl.cs#L957):

> ```
> internal static object UniqueElement(IList list)
> {
>     int size = list.Count;
>     if (size == 0)
>     {
>         return null;
>     }
>     object first = list[0];
>     for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
>     {
>         if (list[i] != first)
>         {
>             throw new NonUniqueResultException(size);
>         }
>     }
>     return first;
> }
> ```

Further, to make it return single scalar value instead of row, you need to use generic overload [`UniqueResult<T>`](http://mausch.github.io/nhibernate-3.2.0GA/html/901fd037-a4f8-f028-8ceb-f02f1f0fd5b6.htm). You need to specify generic parameter (`<string>` in your case; depends on what you are returning) to it.